# getting a full link url in rails 2 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

How can i get the full url with the host name in rails 2

what i'm looking for is to use `url_for` in a model class and append the current host url at the beginning

e.g.

calling this from a model class

> url_for(:controller => 'wiki', :action => 'show', :project_id => page.project, :id => page.title)

and this should return

> http://www.hostname.com/wiki/show/projectname/wikipageid

Answer (score 1):

Include the following modules in your Model

```
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include ActionDispatch::Routing
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Then you can create a function called generete_url and call url_for into that function

```
 class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
   include ActionView::Helpers
   include ActionDispatch::Routing
   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers


   def generate_url

     url_for(:host => "abcd",:action => 'new', :controller => 'users', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'https') 
   end   
 end
```

This is my user model and when I do this I get the ouput

```
u = User.new
u.generate_url 
# => https://abcd/users/new
```

Comment: i got this error `undefined method 'url_for' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Edited the answer please check